# How to get the value from a text input field in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, user-input

I tried to get the input first and last name from the user, but I'm getting I'm undefined results for the both of them.

```js
function getTextField() {
  var fname = document.getElementsByClassName("fname").value;
  var lname = document.getElementsByClassName("lname").value;

  var message = fname + "\n" + lname;
  document.getElementsByClassName("get")[0].innerHTML = message;
}
```

```html
<form name="cost" autocomplete="on">
  First Name:
  <br>
  <input type="text" name="fname" required placeholder="Enter the first name" pattern="[A-Za-z\-]+" maxlength="25">
  <br>Last Name:
  <br>
  <input type="text" name="lname" required placeholder="Enter the last name" pattern="[A-Za-z\-]+" maxlength="25">
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="button" onClick="getTextField()" value="Place Order!" />
  <br>
  <br> <span class="get"></span>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the name fields by `class` rather than the `name` attribute.

Use `getElementsByName` instead of `getElementsByClassName`

```js
function getTextField() {
  var fname = document.getElementsByName("fname")[0].value;
  var lname = document.getElementsByName("lname")[0].value;

  var message = fname + "\n" + lname;
  document.getElementsByClassName("get")[0].innerHTML = message;
}
```

```html
<form name="cost" autocomplete="on">
  First Name:
  <br>
  <input type="text" name="fname" required placeholder="Enter the first name" pattern="[A-Za-z\-]+" maxlength="25">
  <br>Last Name:
  <br>
  <input type="text" name="lname" required placeholder="Enter the last name" pattern="[A-Za-z\-]+" maxlength="25">
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="button" onClick="getTextField()" value="Place Order!" />
  <br>
  <br> <span class="get"></span>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm new to javascript and I appreciate the help :).